# Error when I run executable of cpp source in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When I run the executable`.\helloworld` in VS Code, I get a problem. But it works fine from PowerShell. Could you please guide me to solve the problem?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

```
'c:\pathtofile\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.13.9-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-gqe1reht.z01' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-f5jmmmsy.gys' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-nmujsnhw.lyf' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-rnomudxw.tbv' '--dbgExe=C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'
PS C:\pathtofile> .\helloworld
.\helloworld : The term '.\helloworld' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that     the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\helloworld
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\helloworld:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
```

[image]

Comment: Chances are when you start the debugger the working directory isn't the same as the directory containing the executable

Comment: What documentation can you show that `helloworld` exists in `C:\pathtofile`?

Comment: I need to play around with VSCode again to see if it really is this difficult to use. I didn't like it when it first came out, but it can't still be this annoying, can it?

Comment: It’s not even annoying. It just takes a bit of reading up front. If the project uses cmake it’s dirt simple.

Comment: Via the VS code, I can open the source code and create its executable. However, when I want to run the executable, vs code shows me the above message. On the other hand, the executable runs from the powershell.